# Characterization of pseudo split epimorphisms in Cat

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is there an easy way to characterize pseudo split epimorphisms in Cat?

Obs: A pseudo split epimorphism in Cat is a functor $F: E\to B $ such that there is a functor $ M: B\to E $ and a natural isomorphism $\alpha : FM\to Id _ B $.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of characterization are you looking for? The definition is pretty easy as it is.

Comment: Sorry for delaying. I was looking for something easily verifiable. Like "the monomorphisms are the faithful embeddings" . Or like the following article: http://www.mat.uc.pt/preprints/ps/p0116.ps